# Tuning Performance for Java on Linux and MariaDB

Tags: java, mysql, linux, multithreading, mariadb

I built a java program that connects to a local server and pulls information, then puts it in a mysql database (using jdbc and prepared statements). The program also creates many threads to do this. On the programming environment on my Mac OSX, it runs at a great speed with a single 2.3 ghz processor. I have now moved it to a VPS, installed mariaDB and the VPS has 3gb of ram, and 2 2.4ghz processors, but it runs slower than on my mac. What can I do to fix this? I installed alternative JVM's on the linux, I have used visualVM to optimize it. I just can't seem to figure out why creating these threads happens so fast on my mac while running other programs and on this VPS it is extremely slow.

Any help or direction would be a big help!

Comment: I have seen VPS's drag due to high I/O wait times.  I do not know how to resolve that, but maybe it could be discussed with the host, if that is what is plaguing your VPS.  run "top" and look at the 0.0%wa value on the header.  It should be very low number, if not 0.0 when healthy.  I would do this with and without the app running.

Comment: run single- and multithreaded java benchmarks on both machines to make sure VPS is really more performant.

Comment: @MichaelFord it is in the 30% range with the application running. Wouldn't the I/O wait times be for the MariaDB? All this java program is a bridge between the database and this other program so it isn't writing anything to the I/O. Also mariadb is running healthy in this environment.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov is VisualVM a good way of taking benchmarks?

Comment: simply run SPECjvm2008 or other benchmark. Site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance has many useful links.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your waiting on io from the db.  The latency between you and the db is much higher when the db is on a separate machine and has to make its way across a network.

Possible solutions...

Put the db on the same server as the app that's using it, (possibly increasing the memory of the box to accommodate.

That should fix it assuming you can get an appropriately sized box, (if it doesn't then optimizing the config of mysql/mariadb is advisable at that point)

If you need to leave it on separate servers because you are trying to scale horizontally, then consider processing the data in larger batches instead of making small individual sql queries that will incur allot of round trips to the db in a small amount of time.

Comment: They are on the same box. I have upgraded my VPS to a better one with better IO controls. I am using the innodb in mariadb so I have increased that size to 2gbs and I have changed the pool instances from 1 to 8. That is kinda helping anything else I can do on mariadb?